# Using XSLT and SVG to create bar chart from XML - Scaling Bar Chart

Tags: xml, xslt, svg

I'm new to XSLT and SVG and have already done a lot of research. I've seen some answers on here that look close to what I need help with but not quite working for me. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm pulling an XML file from an SQL db that looks like this:

```
<Report>
  <Title>Step Status Sums Report</Title>
  <RESULTS>
    <ROW>
      <PASSED>2784</PASSED>
      <FAILED>73</FAILED>
      <CAUTION>29</CAUTION>
      <BLOCKED>27</BLOCKED>
      <NOTRUN>3776</NOTRUN>
    </ROW>
  </RESULTS>
</Report>
```

By an online Project Management tool I only have the capabilities of transforming this data using xslt version 1.0 and SVG.

**What I want**: a simple bar graph (this data will change with different projects by the way - so not THIS specific data necessarily).

This is what I've tried and I know probably looks like a terrible construction because I'm trying to follow things that look similar online.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/RESULTS">
  <svg width="650" height="500">
  <g id="axis" transform="translate(0 500) scale(1 -1)">
  <line id="axis-y" x1="30" y1="20" x2="30" y2="450" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
  <line id="axis-x" x1="30" y1="20" x2="460" y2="20"  style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
  </g>  
  <xsl:for-each select="ROW">
   <g id="bars" transform="translate(30 479) scale(1 -430)">
    <rect x="30" y="0" width="50" height="{PASSED}"  style="fill:rgb(81,223,13);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0"/>     
    <rect x="100" y="0" width="50" height="{FAILED}"  style="fill:rgb(224,12,12);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0"/>  
    <rect x="170" y="0" width="50" height="{CAUTION}"  style="fill:rgb(245,136,37);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0"/>  
    <rect x="240" y="0" width="50" height="{BLOCKED}"  style="fill:rgb(248,241,7);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0"/>  
    <rect x="310" y="0" width="50" height="{NOTRUN}"  style="fill:rgb(180,180,180);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0"/>  
  </g> 

    <g id="ROW">
      <rect id="PASSED" x="430" y="80" width="25" height="15"  style="fill:rgb(81,223,13);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1"/>
      <rect id="FAILED" x="430" y="100" width="25" height="15"  style="fill:rgb(224,12,12);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1"/>
      <rect id="CAUTION" x="430" y="120" width="25" height="15"  style="fill:rgb(245,136,37);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1"/>
      <rect id="BLOCKED" x="430" y="140" width="25" height="15"  style="fill:rgb(248,241,7);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1"/>
      <rect id="NOTRUN" x="430" y="160" width="25" height="15"  style="fill:rgb(180,180,180);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1"/>
  </g>
    <text id="PASSED-text" x="465px" y="92px"  style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">  
        <xsl:value-of select="PASSED"/> - Passed  </text>  
    <text id="FAILED-text" x="465px" y="112px"  style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">  
        <xsl:value-of select="FAILED"/> - Failed </text>  
    <text id="key3-text" x="465px" y="132px"  style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">  
        <xsl:value-of select="CAUTION"/> - Caution </text>  
    <text id="key4-text" x="465px" y="152px"  style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">  
        <xsl:value-of select="BLOCKED"/> - Blocked </text>  
    <text id="key5-text" x="465px" y="172px"  style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">  
        <xsl:value-of select="NOTRUN"/> - Not Run </text> 
  <g id="title">
      <text x="325px" y="20px"  style="text-anchor:middle;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:24;font-family:Arial">
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>  </text>
  </g>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </svg>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As the graph image show: [image]

the bars aren't pulling in the correct height. Everything is clearly not scaled right and I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Your XSLT does not match your XML: `<xsl:template match="/RESULTS">` selects nothing!

Comment: @michael.hor257k - yeah you would think so from typical xslt/xml format but there is something going on in the back end of the software tool that uses that instead of the typical way of selecting from an XML file because, from my SQL query, it will automatically generate a default xslt template and "/RESULTS" is what automatically populates to select.

Comment: I am not sure what you're saying here. Your XML's root element is `<Report>` so clearly the path `/RESULTS` does not select anything. If you see a different result then either your XML or your XSLT (or both) is not what you think it is - or your tool is using some different language.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry. I just realized from your question that I should have left the <Report> section out. The XSLT template (within the online tool) is only applied to the RESULTS section. Didn't realize that until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do this, but here's a quick fix:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:variable name="max">
    <xsl:for-each select="Report/RESULTS/ROW/*">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<svg width="650" height="500">
  <g id="axis" transform="translate(0 500) scale(1 -1)">
  <line id="axis-y" x1="30" y1="20" x2="30" y2="450" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
  <line id="axis-x" x1="30" y1="20" x2="460" y2="20"  style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
  </g>  
  <xsl:for-each select="Report/RESULTS/ROW">
   <g id="bars" transform="translate(30 479) scale(1 -430)">
    <rect x="30" y="0" width="50" height="{PASSED div $max}"  style="fill:rgb(81,223,13);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0"/>     
    <rect x="100" y="0" width="50" height="{FAILED div $max}"  style="fill:rgb(224,12,12);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0"/>  
    <rect x="170" y="0" width="50" height="{CAUTION div $max}"  style="fill:rgb(245,136,37);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0"/>  
    <rect x="240" y="0" width="50" height="{BLOCKED div $max}"  style="fill:rgb(248,241,7);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0"/>  
    <rect x="310" y="0" width="50" height="{NOTRUN div $max}"  style="fill:rgb(180,180,180);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0"/>  
  </g> 
...
```

Comment: GREAT! This is better than my quick fix. I created a total and divided by total, but that obviously leaves a lot of white space.