# Using XSLT to create SVG

Tags: xml, xslt, svg

I have an XML file that stores data about classes at a school. I'm just starting to mess around with SVG, so made an SVG file to represent the enrollment numbers in each class. Here's a shrunken version of what I came up with:

[image]

The first bar represents the 25 students enrolled in the first class and so on.

Since I've also learned some basic XSLT, I'd like to see if I can pull in those enrollment numbers from the XML file posted below instead of just putting the numbers in manually (like I did to create the image above) since that is too easy. That is where I'm having trouble. I have most of the info correct I believe, but if you take a look at my XSLT file below, you'll see I have the height of each rectangle set to 15 and I would like to multiply that by the enrollment number (so the height of the first bar should be 15*25, with the 25 being pulled from the XML file via XSLT. The second bar should be 15*20, since the enrollment of the second class is 20, and so on). I started out well and I think I'm close, but after I started adding templates, the bars disappeared. Any help would be appreciated!

Current XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- main template -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- root element is svg and its namespace -->
    <svg version="1.0"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


        <!-- Vertical red line -->
        <line x1="30" y1="35" x2="30" y2="500"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3" />
        <!-- Horizontal red line -->
        <line x1="30" y1="500" x2="500" y2="500"
        style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3" />

        <!-- apply templates to display rectangle bars-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="courses/course/enrollment" />
      </svg>
  </xsl:template>

        <!-- Rectangle 1 template -->
        <xsl:template match="enrollment[1]">
        <!-- Blue Rectangle 1 (341-01) -->
        <rect x="40" y="{500-@height}" width="30" height="{15*.}"
        style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- Rectangle 2 template -->
        <xsl:template match="enrollment[2]">
        <!-- Blue Rectangle 2 (341-02) -->
        <rect x="100" y="{500-@height}" width="30" height="{15*.}"
        style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </xsl:template>

        <!-- Rectangle 3 template -->
        <xsl:template match="enrollment[3]">
        <!-- Blue Rectangle 3 (341-03) -->
        <rect x="160" y="{500-@height}" width="30" height="{15*.}"
        style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </xsl:template>

           <!-- Rectangle 4 template -->
        <xsl:template match="enrollment[4]">
        <!-- Blue Rectangle 4 (368-01) -->
        <rect x="220" y="{500-@height}" width="30" height="{15*.}"
        style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </xsl:template>

           <!-- Rectangle 4 template -->
        <xsl:template match="enrollment[4]">
        <!-- Blue Rectangle 5 (375-01) -->
        <rect x="280" y="{500-@height}" width="30" height="{15*.}"
        style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </xsl:template>

           <!-- Rectangle 4 template -->
        <xsl:template match="enrollment[4]">
        <!-- Blue Rectangle 6 (385-01) -->
        <rect x="340" y="{500-@height}" width="30" height="{15*.}"
        style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </xsl:template>

           <!-- Rectangle 5 template -->
        <xsl:template match="enrollment[5]">
        <!-- Blue Rectangle 7 (413-01) -->
        <rect x="400" y="{500-@height}" width="30" height="{15*.}"
        style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<courses>
  <course number="3221" credits="4.0">
    <title>Physics</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="Classroom">
      <enrollment>25</enrollment>
      <room>EA244</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Herman</first>
        <last>Johnson</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
    <section number="02" delivery="Online">
      <enrollment>20</enrollment>
      <instructor>
        <first>Herman</first>
        <last>Johnson</last>
      </instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Mike</first>
        <last>Miller</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
    <section number="03" delivery="Classroom">
      <enrollment>12</enrollment>
      <room>SH102</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Allison</first>
        <last>Sweeney</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>
  <course number="1318" credits="4.0">
      <title>Psychology</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="Classroom">
      <enrollment>9</enrollment>
      <room>AT102</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Mike</first>
        <last>Miller</last>
      </instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Alex</first>
        <last>Holmquist</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>
  <course number="3715" credits="4.0">
      <title>Biology</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="ITV">
      <enrollment>18</enrollment>
            <room>EA244</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Mike</first>
        <last>Miller</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>
  <course number="3815" credits="3.0">
      <title>Calculus</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="Classroom">
      <enrollment>16</enrollment>
            <room>ST108</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Herman</first>
        <last>Johnson</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>
  <course number="4113" credits="3.0">
      <title>Chemistry</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="Online">
      <enrollment>20</enrollment>
      <instructor>
        <first>Mike</first>
        <last>Miller</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>
</courses>
```

EDIT:

Here is what the SVG code should look like after the XSLT transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0">

   <line style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3" y2="500" x2="30" y1="35" x1="30" />
   <line style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3" y2="500" x2="500" y1="500" x1="30" />
   <rect style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" height="375" width="30" y="125" x="40" />
   <rect style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" height="300" width="30" y="200" x="100" />
   <rect style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" height="180" width="30" y="320" x="160" />
   <rect style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" height="135" width="30" y="365" x="220" />
   <rect style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" height="270" width="30" y="230" x="280" />
   <rect style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" height="240" width="30" y="260" x="340" />
   <rect style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width: 3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" height="300" width="30" y="200" x="400" />
</svg>
```

To reiterate, the height of each rectangle should come from whatever the enrollment number is multiplied by 15 (otherwise the rectangle bars will be too short). I would also like it to go in order, so the first bar should be the first enrollment number times 15, and the last bar should be the last enrollment number times 15.

Comment: I'm trying to re-create the same image above by using XSLT in case that wasn't completely clear.

Comment: I don't think you need an individual template for each bar. You may not know how many sections are there, and even if you do, such coding is unnecessarily repetitive. Compute the bar's x coordinate using the position() function, and its height from the value of `enrollment`. --  Note also that you are referring to something that doesn't exist here: `y="{500-@height}"`.

Comment: In order for the bottom of the rectangles to line up with the horizontal red line, I need to subtract whatever the height is from 500. Or is there another way to ensure they line up with the horizontal line?

Comment: Could you post the result you are after **as code**?

Comment: The desired SVG code has been added to the bottom of my post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779904/creating-a-svg-bar-chart-using-xslt-to-xml-transformation-output-table I guess my bar is overlapping plz go through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me suggest the following as your starting point:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <svg version="1.0"> 
        <g transform="translate(0 500) scale(1 -1)">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="courses/course/section"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
    <rect x="{40 * position()}" width="30" height="{enrollment}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See also:
[Using XSLT and SVG to create bar chart from XML - Scaling Bar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765586/using-xslt-and-svg-to-create-bar-chart-from-xml-scaling-bar-chart/24766464#24766464)

Comment: Perfect, I can definitely work with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put the declaration of the SVG namespace on the root element of the stylesheet as only then it applies to all result elements in all templates. With your current code only the `svg` element gets the right namespace while your rectangles in the other templates end up being in no namespace.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately, my code still isn't working.

Comment: The `y` attributes use the expression `@height` but that attribute is not defined in the input sample you posted.

Comment: When I write it like that, is it trying to pull a height attribute from the XML file? I want it to subtract the value of the height attribute that's declared within that same rectangle in the XSLT file , just a little ways to the right of the Y attribute. Looks like this: height="{15*.}"

Comment: If the height gets bigger and the Y attribute stays the same, then the positioning of the rectangle gets screwed up.

Comment: Define a variable `<xsl:variable name="height" select="15 * ."/>`, then use `y="500 - $height"`.