# Multiply <xsl:value-of> result by -1

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, svg

Novice/beginner XSL user here.

I have something like the following template in my XSLT document:

`<xsl:template name="getpoint">
        <xsl:param name="nodenum"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="//nodeCoord[nodeNumber=$nodenum]/nodeXCoord"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//nodeCoord[nodeNumber=$nodenum]/nodeYCoord"/>
</xsl:template>`

The full XSLT document is being used to produce an SVG graphic. However, I wish to flip the browser's Y coordinate system upside down since my source data assumes a traditional coordinate system.

My question is very simple: how do I multiply `nodeYCoord` by -1 and have that result sent to the browser instead of the value produced by the `<xsl:value-of>` element?

EDIT: Please do not provide alternative methods on how to flip the Y coordinate system. I have researched this, and for my specific application I am pretty certain this is the best way to go about it (assuming I can make it work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question if very simple: how do I multiply nodeYCoord by -1 and
>   have that result sent to the browser instead of the value produced by
>   the `<xsl:value-of>` element?

And the answer is very simple, too: use the minus sign. Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//nodeCoord[nodeNumber=$nodenum]/nodeYCoord"/>
```

write:

```
<xsl:value-of select="-//nodeCoord[nodeNumber=$nodenum]/nodeYCoord"/>
```

> Please do not provide alternative methods on how to flip the Y
>   coordinate system. I have researched this, and for my specific
>   application I am pretty certain this is the best way to go about it
>   (assuming I can make it work).

Perhaps you should take another look at it.

Comment: Adding the negative sign is the first thing I tried. It is not working in Internet Explorer. The image renders perfectly without the negative, but does not render at all when I add it. The files are stored locally so I can't do the transformation in Chrome as it won't allow local XSL transformation. 

I'd love to hear your alternative idea for flipping the Y. I have tried about 5 different ways though and none of them work in this situation.

Comment: michael: i set up IIS on my localhost, and this DOES work in chrome! thanks a lot. it takes FOREVER to render, though - much longer than internet explorer. better than nothing though.

Comment: @RickTeachey **1.** I don't see why this wouldn't work universally, but just in case, `<xsl:value-of select="//nodeCoord[nodeNumber=$nodenum]/nodeYCoord * -1"/>` should do the same thing.  **2.** This has nothing to do with speed. But using `//` might have: in XSLT, it pays to be explicit and write out the full path. **3.** Not sure what "this situation" is. See if this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108217/using-xslt-to-create-svg/25108778#25108778

Comment: The alternative XPath formulation doesn't work in IE, either. Works in Chrome. ???? Weird. Thanks for the tip on faster paths, I'll try that and have a look at the link as well.

Comment: @RickTeachey I suggest you test this issue in isolation. See what you get when using the input and the stylesheet here: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKvQ

Comment: Hmmm. that does work in IE. must be something else going on in my larger documents. if you want to fiddle with them, here are samples (tried adding an if-then-else structure in order to avoid "-0", but it isn't working in IE, either): http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2BU/1

Comment: @RickTeachey You need to test this with a XSLT 1.0 processor: http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2BU/1

Answer (score 0):

Save your value to a variable and then use it in an xpath expression

```
<xsl:variable name="yval" select="//nodeCoord[nodeNumber=$nodenum]/nodeYCoord/text()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="-1 * $yval"/>
```

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know you could do that. Thanks a heap.

Comment: Quick question: can this variable be "reused"? I'm going to be doing this same task several thousand times.

Comment: You can re-reference a variable throughout the template or construct a new variable with an expression. Within XSLT, you cannot reassign a value to a variable.

Comment: Unfortunately this probably won't work for me as given, then. So the `$yval` variable is global? It is not local to just the current template and doesn't get "flushed" once that iteration of the template is complete? Is there a way around this?

Comment: You cannot reassign it within an execution of a template.  When the template is called again, it can be assigned a new variable.  If you need a global variable, you can assign that at the top of your stylesheet before the template definitions.