# XSLT: Combining Muenchian grouping with SVG bar chart

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, group-by, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a SVG-bar chart in which the daily sales are displayed. That means the xml-data below has to be grouped by the attribute "date". Since I have to use XSLT 1.0 I have to do "Muenchian grouping" or some other work-around.

```
<orders>
    <order id="01" date="2015-01-01">
        <product price="20">Apple</product>
        <product price="5">Pear</product>
    </order>
    <order id="02" date="2015-01-01">
        <product price="20">Pear</product>
        <product price="40">Plum</product>
    </order>
</orders>
```

I was able to draw a SVG-bar chart without grouping the entries. So the drawing part isn't the problem. There are a lot of Muenchian grouping examples here on Stackoverflow but I'm just not able to get it to work.. Thank you for your help.

XSL:

```
<xsl:variable name="baseline" select="480"/> 
<xsl:key name="order-by-date" match="order" use="@date" />
<xsl:template match="orders">
    <svg:svg>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="order[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('order-by-date',@date)[1])]"  />      
    </svg:svg>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="order">    
    <xsl:for-each select="key('order-by-date', @date)">
    <!-- draw the Rectangles (bars) for each group -->
        <xsl:variable name="x-offset" select="40 + position() * 40" />
        <xsl:variable name="y-offset" select="$baseline"/>
        <xsl:variable name="y" select="$y-offset - sum(current()/product/@price)"/>

        <!-- attributes of the rectangle -->

        <svg:path>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:text>fill:</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="blue"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:attribute name="d">
                <!-- move to the lower left corner of the rectangle -->
                <xsl:text>M </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$x-offset - 10"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$y-offset"/>
                <!-- draw line to the upper left corner of the rectangle -->
                <xsl:text> L </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$x-offset - 10"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$y"/>
                <!-- draw line to the upper right corner of the rectangle -->
                <xsl:text> L </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$x-offset + 10"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$y"/>
                <!-- draw line to the lower right corner of the rectangle -->
                <xsl:text> L </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$x-offset + 10"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$y-offset"/>
                <!-- close path and fill the rectangle -->
                <xsl:text> Z</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </svg:path>
        <!-- write Date underneath each bar -->
        <svg:text style="writing-mode:tb" x="{position()*30 + 50}" y="{$baseline + 20}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(@datum,9,2)" />
        </svg:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you possible show the output you expecting in this case? Thank you!

Comment: "*I'm trying to create a SVG-bar chart in which the daily sales are displayed.*  What exactly are "daily sales" in your example? Just the sum of all prices for that day? -- P.S. If you want a bar chart, why aren't you using rectangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to start with an example spanning more than one date:

**XML**

```
<orders>
    <order id="01" date="2015-01-01">
        <product price="20">Apple</product>
        <product price="5">Pear</product>
    </order>
    <order id="02" date="2015-01-01">
        <product price="20">Pear</product>
        <product price="40">Plum</product>
    </order>
    <order id="03" date="2015-01-02">
        <product price="20">Apple</product>
        <product price="40">Plum</product>
    </order>
</orders>
```

Then you could construct a stylesheet along the lines of:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="order-by-date" match="order" use="@date" />

<xsl:template match="/orders">
    <svg version="1.0"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="order[generate-id()=generate-id(key('order-by-date',@date)[1])]" />
    </svg>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="sum(key('order-by-date',@date)/product/@price)"/>
    <!-- create a svg object here, using the y dimension -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My own preference would be to use a rectangle as the object to create, e.g.:

```
<rect x="{40 * position()}" width="30" height="{$y}"/>
```

See also:
[Using XSLT to create SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108217/using-xslt-to-create-svg/25108778#25108778)

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you for your help! This is exactly what I was trying to achieve.