# Using an xslt file to turn xml file into svg?

Tags: css, xml, xslt, svg

I need to make an xslt that turns my xml file into an svg.

The can't load the desired image, but it's basically a bar graph with a title at the top that says "Fall 2018 enrollment" and the height of each bar in the graph is based on the enrollment element in the xml file (so it's not hard coded).

I've been fiddling around with it a bit but I really don't know what to do.

This is the xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<courses>
  <course number="341" credits="4.0">
    <title>Data Structures</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="Classroom">
      <enrollment>15</enrollment>
      <room>EA244</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Nicole</first>
        <last>Anderson</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
    <section number="02" delivery="Online">
      <enrollment>10</enrollment>
      <instructor>
        <first>Nicole</first>
        <last>Anderson</last>
      </instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
        <last>Lin</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
    <section number="03" delivery="Classroom">
      <enrollment>12</enrollment>
      <room>SH102</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Mark</first>
        <last>Funk</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>
  <course number="368" credits="4.0">
      <title>Introduction to Bioinformatics</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="Classroom">
      <enrollment>9</enrollment>
      <room>AT102</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
        <last>Lin</last>
      </instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Mingrui</first>
        <last>Zhang</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>
  <course number="375" credits="4.0">
      <title>Computer Systems</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="ITV">
      <enrollment>18</enrollment>
            <room>EA244</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
        <last>Lin</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>
  <course number="385" credits="3.0">
      <title>Applied Database Management Systems</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="Classroom">
      <enrollment>26</enrollment>
            <room>ST108</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Nicole</first>
        <last>Anderson</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>
  <course number="413" credits="3.0">
      <title>Advanced Networking</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="Online">
      <enrollment>10</enrollment>
      <instructor>
        <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
        <last>Lin</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>
</courses>
```

￼
This is my attempt at an xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="style"/>

    <xsl:param name="width" select="40"/><!--width of bars-->
    <xsl:param name="space" select="10"/><!--space between bars-->

    <xsl:variable name="max-y" select="//enrollment[not(//enrollement &gt; .)[1]"/>

    <xsl:template match="courses">
        <svg>
           <defs>
              <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
                 g.bar text {
                    font-family: Arial;
                    text-anchor: middle;
                    fill: white;
                 }
                 g.bar rect {
                    fill: blue;
                 }
              ]]>   
              </style> 
           </defs>
           <g transform="translate(10,10)">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="course"/>
           </g> 
        </svg>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="course">
        <xsl:variable name="prev-course" select="preceding-sibling::course "/>
        <g class="course" id="course-{position()}" transform="translate({
                  count($prev-course/section) * ($width + $space)
                  + count($prev-course) * $space
                  })">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="section" />
        </g>   
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:variable name="prev-section" select="preceding-sibling::section "/>
        <g class="section" id="section-{position()}" transform="translate({
                  count($prev-section/enrollment) * ($width + $space)
                  + count($prev-section) * $space
                  })">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="enrollment" />
        </g> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="enrollment">
        <xsl:variable name="idx" select="count(preceding-sibling::enrollment)" />
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="$idx * ($width + $space)" />
        <g class="bar">
           <rect x="{$pos}" y="{$max-y - .}" height="{.}" width="{$width}" />
           <text x="{$pos + $width div 2.0}" y="{$max-y - $space}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           </text>
        </g>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Here's a tutorial: http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XSLT_to_generate_SVG_tutorial.  As is, this question is really too broad to properly answer.  Perhaps after reading  the tutorial you could repost it with your attempt and what isn't working?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108217/using-xslt-to-create-svg/25108778#25108778

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `<xsl:variable name="max-y" select="//enrollment[not(//enrollement &gt; .)[1]"/>` lacks a closing brackets, I guess you want `<xsl:variable name="max-y" select="//enrollment[not(//enrollement &gt; .)][1]"/>`.

I would probably use

```
<xsl:variable name="max-y">
  <xsl:for-each select="//enrollment">
    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

however.