# How to maximise bars in a SVG chart

Tags: xml, xslt, svg

I have an XML doc with data I'd like to plot in a SVG graph using XSL. The chart is visible but the individual bars aren't filling the width of the chart and are just about visible on the Y axis. (see below).

[image]

How can I get the width of the bars to fill the length of the chart?

Currently the bar width is specified from the corresponding values in the  XML doc.

Here is my XML code:

```
<xml>
<graph2>
    <averageLowTemperatures>
        <January>3.7</January>
        <February>3.4</February>
        <March>5.0</March>
        <April>6.4</April>
        <May>9.4</May>
        <June>12.3</June>
        <July>14.6</July>
        <August>14.7</August>
        <September>12.5</September>
        <October>9.6</October>
        <November>6.2</November>
        <December>4.7</December>
    </averageLowTemperatures>    
</graph2>
```

And here is my XSL code:

```
<xsl:variable name="max">
        <xsl:for-each select="xml/graph2/averageLowTemperatures/*">
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/><xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="axis" transform="translate(0 500) scale(1 -1)">
            <!--Y Axis line-->
            <line id="axis-y" x1="30" y1="20" x2="30" y2="510" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
            <!--X Axis line-->
            <line id="axis-x" x1="30" y1="20" x2="700" y2="20"  style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
        </g>

        <xsl:for-each select="xml/graph2/averageLowTemperatures">
            <g>
                <rect x="31" y="5" width="{January div $max}" height="35" id="Jan"/>
                <rect x="31" y="45" width="{February div $max}" height="35" id="Feb"/>
                <rect x="31" y="85" width="{March div $max}" height="35" id="Mar"/>
                <rect x="31" y="125" width="{April div $max}" height="35" id="Apr"/>
                <rect x="31" y="165" width="{May div $max}" height="35" id="May"/>
                <rect x="31" y="205" width="{June div $max}" height="35" id="Jun"/>
                <rect x="31" y="245" width="{July div $max}" height="35" id="Jul"/>
                <rect x="31" y="285" width="{August div $max}" height="35" id="Aug"/>
                <rect x="31" y="325" width="{September div $max}" height="35" id="Sep"/>
                <rect x="31" y="365" width="{October div $max}" height="35" id="Oct"/>
                <rect x="31" y="405" width="{November div $max}" height="35" id="Nov"/>
                <rect x="31" y="445" width="{December div $max}" height="33" id="Dec"/>

            </g> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </svg>
```

Is this issue being caused as the SVG graph width (700) is far larger than the values of the bars (14.7) and thus they are barely visible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765586/using-xslt-and-svg-to-create-bar-chart-from-xml-scaling-bar-chart/24766464#24766464

Comment: And this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108217/using-xslt-to-create-svg/25108778#25108778

Comment: @michael.hor257k I originally used these examples to produce a vertical bar chart which displays perfectly but I am unsure on what is causing my issue now, any pointers?

Comment: Not unless you post a reproducible example - see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k does the code supplied in the question not satisfy a reproducible example? All that is missing is '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
<xsl:template match="/">' from the XSL doc and the link to it in the XML. Apologies, fairly new here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the simplest way I can think of to get the bars:

**XML**

```
<xml>
    <graph2>
        <averageLowTemperatures>
            <January>3.7</January>
            <February>3.4</February>
            <March>5.0</March>
            <April>6.4</April>
            <May>9.4</May>
            <June>12.3</June>
            <July>14.6</July>
            <August>14.7</August>
            <September>12.5</September>
            <October>9.6</October>
            <November>6.2</November>
            <December>4.7</December>
        </averageLowTemperatures>    
    </graph2>
</xml>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:variable name="temperatures" select="graph2/averageLowTemperatures/*" />
    <xsl:variable name="max">
        <xsl:for-each select="$temperatures">
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <svg>
        <g id="bars" transform="translate(0, 500) scale(1 -1)">
            <xsl:for-each select="$temperatures">
                <rect x="{40 * position()}" width="30" height="{. div $max * 500}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </g>
    </svg>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="bars" transform="translate(0, 600) scale(1 -1)">
    <rect x="40" width="30" height="125.850340136054"/>
    <rect x="80" width="30" height="115.646258503401"/>
    <rect x="120" width="30" height="170.068027210884"/>
    <rect x="160" width="30" height="217.687074829932"/>
    <rect x="200" width="30" height="319.727891156463"/>
    <rect x="240" width="30" height="418.367346938776"/>
    <rect x="280" width="30" height="496.598639455782"/>
    <rect x="320" width="30" height="500"/>
    <rect x="360" width="30" height="425.170068027211"/>
    <rect x="400" width="30" height="326.530612244898"/>
    <rect x="440" width="30" height="210.884353741497"/>
    <rect x="480" width="30" height="159.863945578231"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Rendered**

[image]

Note the multiplication of the $max value by the intended height of the bar section. Without this, the calculation would return only the *ratio* of the current value to the max value.